# SwiftUI - Pass Nested Array of Objects to Details View

Tags: arrays, swiftui, pass-data

I'm trying to pass a data object that contains a nested array of objects from the Master view to the Details view. Currently, I'm able to display the parent level of the data object, but I'm struggling to try to figure out how to pass it's a nested array of data on to the details page. Below is a sample of my data model and how I'm going about displaying the information currently. I'm not sure what I need to type for the code where I'm passing the information on in the NavigationLink element. I'm sure there's probably a better way to do this, however, I'm just a designer trying to figure this out for prototyping reasons.

//Passports.swift //

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Passports: Identifiable {
    let id : Int
    let passportPremium: Bool
    let passportActive: Bool
    let passportTitle: String
    let passportDates: String
    let venues: [Venue]
    }

struct Venue: Identifiable {

    let id = UUID()
    let title : String
    let venueArea: String
    let venueItems: [venueItem]
}

struct venueItem {
    let title: String
    let productDescription: String
    let productPrice: Double
    let productType: String
    let newStatus: Bool
    let diningPlan: Bool
    let kidFriendly: Bool
    let vegetarian: Bool
    let glutenFree: Bool
    let featuredProduct: Bool
    let containsAlcohol: Bool
}


extension Passports {
    static func all() -> [Passports] {
        return [
            Passports (
                id: 1001,
                passportPremium: false,
                passportActive: true,
                passportTitle : "Passport Title Example",
                passportDates: "October 20 - November 3, 2019",
                venues: [
                    Venue (
                        title: "Venue Name",
                        venueArea: "Germany",
                        venueItems: [
                                venueItem (
                                title: "Potato Dumpling",
                                productDescription: "Potato Dumpling with Mushroom Sauce",
                                productPrice: 0.00,
                                productType: "Food",
                                newStatus: false,
                                mealPlan: false,
                                kidApproved: true,
                                vegetarian: false,
                                glutenFree: false,
                                featuredProduct: false,
                                containsAlcohol: false
                            ),
                            venueItem (
                                title: "Pork Schnitzel",
                                productDescription: "Pork Schnitzel with Mushroom Sauce and Spaetzle",
                                productPrice: 0.00,
                                productType: "Food",
                                newStatus: false,
                                mealPlan: false,
                                kidApproved: false,
                                vegetarian: false,
                                glutenFree: false,
                                featuredProduct: false,
                                containsAlcohol: false
                            )
])
]
            )

        ]

    }

}
```

//PassportsView //

```
import SwiftUI

struct PassportsView: View {

   var model = Passports.all()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ForEach(self.model) { item in
                NavigationLink (destination: PassportDetails(passportTitle: item.passportTitle, venues: [Venue()]  ) ) {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(item.passportTitle)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    Text(item.passportDates)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 120)
                                .background(Color("Purple"))

                            .cornerRadius(6)
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// PassportDetails //

```
struct PassportDetails: View {
var passportTitle = "Passport Name"
var venues: [Venue] = [
    Venue(title: "Test Venue", venueArea: "Test Area", venueItems: [venueItem]())
]

var venueProd: [venueItem] = [
    venueItem(title: "Test item", productDescription: "Test Description", productPrice: 9.99, productType: "Food", newStatus: false, mealPlan: true, kidApproved: false, vegetarian: false, glutenFree: false, featuredProduct: false, containsAlcohol: false)
]

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Test")
                Spacer()
                Text("9.99")
            }
        }
    }.navigationBarTitle(Text(passportTitle))
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PassportDetails` do the following:

`var venues: [Venue]`

and in `Passports` do this:

```
NavigationLink (destination: PassportDetails(passportTitle: item.passportTitle, venues: item.venues) )
```

PS: You should do the same for the passportTitle, meaning in `PassportDetails` put `var passportTitle: String`

Comment: Based on the above suggestions, now I'm trying to figure out how to just display the array of venues in a list.

List(self.venues) { ven in
                NavigationLink () {
                    HStack {
                        Text(ven.title)
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: What issue are you facing ?

Comment: It's giving me the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" when I'm trying to display the value in the Text element.

Comment: You can ask another question and addd more info and I can try helping there